# Is there a way of finding local maxima and minima for high-degree polynomials?

Tags: derivatives, roots

How can I find the points that makes the derivative equal zero?

For example: $f(x)=x^5+3x^4+2x^3+6x^2+3x-1$

It is hard to solve the fourth degree polynomial obtaining from $f'(x)$.

Comment: Yes, it's hard (once upon a time it was a discovery basically worth a professorate on its own). But it's basically what you have to do. At least fourth degree polynomials have an exact formula to use.

Comment: @Moo What do you mean by closed form solution and I didn't really get the thing in the link.

Comment: @Moo Oh yes. So that means there are no other ways but solving the equation again.

Comment: @Moo  From his earlier questions, this OP is usually asking about numerical methods in one variable. In particular, Laguerre's method is regarded as better than Newton's for finding complex roots, and Mathrix has asked about both methods. Put it together, I am not sure what this question is asking, especially "It is hard to..."

Comment: @WillJagy I am actually trying to find the two roots of $f(x)$ which are the points where those local maxima-minima's parabolas intersect the x-axis (if they do) by using three successive points in the interval of those parabolas and using those points to find the equation of the parabola and then solving the equation etc. Hope it's clear. I am sorry if I am missing some basic things, I am a high school student.

Comment: So you're trying to solve a fifth degree equation by approximating it by a second degree equation near its extreme points. There must be better ways.